# Understanding Pointer to constant pointer to integer constant (const int * const * variable)

Tags: c, pointers, constants

Given an example

```
const int limit = 500;
const int * const cpci = &limit;
const int * const * pcpci = &cpci;
```

I am having difficulty understanding what the last line means.

Basically in array terms the value pcpci it's just an array of (const int * const)'s. But i can't seem to make multiple copies inside pcpci since it is not supposed to be a constant pointer.

For Example

```
const int limit = 500;
const int * const cpci = &limit;
const int * const * pcpci = &cpci;
const int limit2 = 600;
const int * const cpci2 = &limit2;
*(pcpci+1) = &cpci2;
```

In the last line of the above code i got "error lvalue must be modifiable". But i was wondering why is this happening since pcpci is not a constant pointer and only it's elements should be constant and non modifiable.

Comment: This has nothing to do with arrays.

Comment: "*pcpci it's just an array*" No, pointers are not arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all this statement

```
*(pcpci+1) = &cpci;
```

has undefined behaviour because you may not dereference  a pointer that does not points to an object. You could use this construction if `pcpci` would point to an element of an array and `pcpci + 1` also point to the next element of the same array.

So it would be more coorectly to write

```
*(pcpci) = &cpci;
```

However the object pointed to by `pcpci` is a constant object with type `T const` where T is `const int *`  so it may not be reassigned.

That it would be more clear you can rewrite definition

```
const int * const * pcpci = &cpci;
```

the following way

```
typedef const int * const ConstPointerToConstObject;

ConstPointerToConstObject * pcpci = &cpci;
```

So if to derefernce `pcpci` you will get an object of type `ConstPointerToConstObject` that may not be changed because it is a **constant pointer** to constant object.

Answer (score 2):

> But i was wondering why is this happening since pcpci is not a constant pointer

No, but `*(pcpci+1)` is. It has type `const int* const`. Obviously you can't assign anything to that.